# Call java servlet from other project

Tags: java

I have one Java Web Project (Demo 1) that is running on Apache Tomcat Version 8.0.33 which is installed on Ubuntu 14.04 Server.

Now I am creating a new Java Web Project (Demo 2) and I have to call a Servlet (doPost) with Request Parameter of my already running project (Demo 1) from my project (Demo 2).

And my Java Web Project (Demo 1) is running on **https**
So the Servlet URL is https://shibbolethidp.demo.local/idp/j_security_check

I have also export cert using below command of server where Demo 1 App is running into my local jdk where I am trying to run my Demo 2 App.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\keytool.exe -import -alias shib-idp -file C:\Users\guest\Desktop\Desktop\shib_exportedCert.der -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit
```

My Demo 2 Project code is given below which I am using to call Servlet of Demo 1 Project

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Authn extends HttpServlet {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Authn.class.getName());

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://shibbolethidp.demo.local/idp/j_security_check");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()));
            out.write("xml=xmltest\r\n");
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String response1;
            while ((response1 = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(response1);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run this I am getting the below error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching shibbolethidp.demo.local found
```

I am using jdk1.8.0_60 and Tomcat 8.

Comment: You have a certificate issue since you are using SSL (https).

Comment: @AxelH I have already export cert of server where Demo 1 App is running into my local jdk where I am trying to run my Demo 2 App.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Transport Security (SSL) Workaround for your `localhost` development environment.

Try adding this:

```
public class Authn extends HttpServlet {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Authn.class.getName());

    static {
        //for localhost testing only
        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(
        new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier(){

            public boolean verify(String hostname,
                    javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
                if (hostname.equals("localhost")) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
      // your code here
    }
}
```